# Is it possible to disable the abiity to horizontally scroll inside a Codename One text field

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to disable the user to scroll inside a text field when it is focused? I have tried:

```
pinT = new TextField();
pinT.setSingleLineTextArea(true);
pinT.setScrollSize(new Dimension(0,0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use any of the above. Since the scrolling is native it can't be disabled but you can limit the number of characters that the user can type into the text field using:

```
pint.setMaxSize(charCount);
```